# HF current measurement

Tags: current, resistors, measurement, shunt, hf

I have an assignment, where i'm supposed to (sort of accurately) measure the current drawn by a SIM-card, in the different phases it can operate in. The current is by no means DC, as the SIM-card operates at a clock-frequency of around 5 MHz. I am expecting current peaks in the range of 1mA-40mA. Therefore, my question is: How would you go about measuring such a relatively small HF current?

I have until now experimented with using a shunt resistor in a low-side current sensing configuration. The problem is that I am experiencing that with an increase in frequency, I see an increase in voltage amplitude across the shunt resistor, which I can't really explain. I suspect that some capacitive and/or inductive effects have a significant say at these frequencies and this messes up my measurements. So do any of you have alternative solutions to this measuring problem?

I am using a shunt resistor with a resistance of 0,22 Ohm.

Comment: You have endless options! Rogowski if you have short enough cycles to live with the DC offset. Hall effect should be no problem. Commercial oscilloscope current probes have no problem with 50 MHz.

Comment: Specifically what resistor have you used and how have you connected it to your silicon. Also what is that silicon?

Comment: The part I am struggling with is _The current is by no means DC_.  After that, my mind wandered.

Comment: 1. Haven't heard of Rogowski before. Will look into it. I don't have access to an oscilloscope current probe. Do you reckon a self-wound coil will yield accurate results?

2. The type of resistor might be the problem, yeah. I only have access to power resistors and ordinary leaded resistors at the moment. What do you mean silicon? The setup is built on a breadboard at the moment.

3. Sorry for that phrasing. English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Please start your answers with @ followed by username, no spaces, or the person will not be notified. Rogowski is good for HF AC if you need to see fast transitions. No, far from accurate. You need metal or carbon film resistor. No though-hole power resistors will do.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I'm sorry for not knowing how this works. Still learning :)